# run a gitlab-ci stage only if changes or previous fail

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I'm having a couple of stages. The first one is responsible for setting up docker containers.
This stage might fail due to different reasons.

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
create_buildroot_image:
  stage: createBuildrootImage
  script:
    - *do_docker_login
    - docker build -t $BUILD_ROOT_TAG1 -t $BUILD_ROOT_TAG2 build_root
    - docker push $BUILD_ROOT_TAG1
    - docker push $BUILD_ROOT_TAG2
    - exit 1
  only:
    changes:
      - Dockerfile
      - build_root/*
  tags:
    - docker
```

If this stage fails, the next one fails too. But upon the next commit, the first stage doesn't run again, it gets skipped, causing the next stage to fail again.

How can I make sure that the results of the first stage get cleaned up upon failure and the stage runs again to create a "healthy" environment?

Comment: Is this for merge request or also in general?

Comment: This is the general setting of the repository: this should run every time we push to a work branch. The create_buildroot_image job should run only once if Dockerfile or build_root directory content are not amended, but it should not be skipped when the job failed for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It may not solve your problem, but it might help you along your way.

1. I assume that the `create_buildroot_image` only fails in mergerequests, and that the build in the integration branch always succeeds.
2. I assume that there are only regular builds for the integration branch, but not for feature branches

I am also working with projects based on that assumptions (there are some additional paths for version etc, but they are not important for this outline).

For the integration branch (aka `develop` or `main`) we also build the image - we want to ensure, that this build always works, and therefore it should always run. But to leverage functionality of docker, we also try to pull the image upfront with `docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true`

like

```yaml
create_buildroot_image:
  stage: createBuildrootImage
  script:
    - *do_docker_login
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - >
      docker build
      --pull
      --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
      --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - echo "IMAGE_TO_USE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env # passes on env variable
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:
        - Dockerfile
        - build_root/*
  tags:
    - docker
```

This way we can speed up the build, and reduce the build for the merge request events - but ensure an always working build on our default branch.

On the next stage we also have a environment variable called `IMAGE_TO_USE` at hand to refer to the Image - or at least it is a starting point, how we want to use it is up to you.

But we also want to push that image for our default branch so:

```yaml
Push:
  variables:
    # no need for a git clone, as it is just docker
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: push
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script:
    - *do_docker_login
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

Now we only tag it for the develop branch with latest, so our caching image gets updated.

The tricky part, or the annoying part - we do not know how the image is called from the previous build of the merge request event - we can try to figure it out, with some naming convention or something similar. But this gets really confusing.

Instead we could change the behaviour of the merge request to work with the `Merged Result` (`Settings` -> `General` -> `Merge Requests` -> `Enable merged results pipelines` ). With this setting a merge request will be seen as a whole. So you are not dependent on one commit, but of the results of them all.

Upsides of this approach:

- you only push after the build was done, as it happens in a separate stage, this allows to also do some extra work in here
- it uses caching and utilizes the layering so it should have improved build times vs building all the time from scratch

Downsides:

- the build is happening in mergerequests on each build as soon as you touch some files
- you need to use the environment variable which is passed one in a way that it fits your project

**Summary**

This is just another approach, or a slightly different one, which could benefit your problem. It is not a solution for your question, it just shows an approach, which i am regularly using, and which can solve this problem. The tricky part is wihtin handling of the env variable. I hope i could help somehow

Comment: Is there any chance to make `IMAGE_TO_USE` variable available for upcoming pipeline runs? For that, I'll need to be able to set a variable within a job, and read that, when the pipeline runs next time.

Comment: maybe some part from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69768655/3708208 will be helpful regarding that :) specially the `docker pull` with `export` part - you can always add a prestage for that