# Gitlab CI: old Docker images?

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

Our project uses a multi-stage CI setup where the first stage checks for modification of files like `package-lock.json` and `Gemfile.lock`, compiles all these dependencies and then pushes them to the Gitlab container registry.

Using `--cache-from` in Docker build based on the current mainline branch, this is quite fast and the Docker layering mechanism helps to prevent repetition of steps.

Subsequent stages and jobs then use the Docker image pushed in the first stage as their `image:`.

Abbreviated configuration for readability:

```yaml
stages:
  - create_builder_image
  - test

Create Builder Image:
  stage: create_builder_image
  script:
    - export DOCKER_BRANCH_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    # do stuff to build the image, using cache to speed it up
    - docker push $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$DOCKER_BRANCH_TAG

Run Tests:
  image: $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  stage: test
  script:
    # do stuff in the context of the image build in the first stage
```

Unfortunately, when working on longer-running feature branches, we now have a situation where it looks like the image in the second step is sometimes outdated and not pulling the latest version from the registry before starting the job, which makes subsequent jobs complain about missing dependencies.

Is there anything I can do to force it to always pull the latest image for each job?

Comment: You could use the commit Sha as the docker.tag, this way each pipeline will have it's own docker image based on the git sha

Comment: That would be a fallback solution, but it would either require additional build time for each commit or complex logic to re-use the image of the previous commit as the base for caching. Also, it would clutter the image registry much more, requiring more aggressive cleanup.

Comment: Regarding the re-use of the image, you still can push it with the old name and use it as a fallback, and if the fallback is not there use the latest image or the one from the integration branch for caching. Yes cleanup will be a little bit more challenging, but you can also prefix the tag for easier rules ;)

Comment: What is your [pull policy](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#using-the-always-pull-policy) configuration for the runner? If not set already, it should be set to `always`. Or is the issue with concurrent pipelines building the image with new and old dependencies? (race condition)

Comment: @sytech that sounds like it might indeed solve that problem. Unfortunately we're using the shared CI runners from gitlab.com at the moment. No idea what they're configured to use but I supposed it's something else. Since it's a multi-stage build, concurrency should not be the issue: the second stage is simply not pulling the updated images built in the first stage.

Comment: It should say in the build log what the pull policy is -- gitlab.com should use the "always" policy. As long as you have the "auto-cancel redundant pipelines" setting enabled for the project, you shouldn't have this problem due to the pull policy or the image tag of `CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG`. I would suspect there's some other error that's being overlooked either in the CI configuration, dockerfile, or build script that's not being shown here. Is there a typical fix you use for this? Are you _absolutely sure_ it's not pulling the correct image? Are you using GitLab image registry or another?

Comment: Can you provide the full job script used and relevant parts of the dockerfile? You also seem to mention this happens particularly on _long running_ feature branches. Since you're using `--cache-from` from the image built on your mainline branch, I'll bet there's some connection to changes between your mainline branch, feature branch, and when this issue occurs. I'm guessing the issue is probably not random.

Answer (score 1):

As already written in the comments, i would not use the `$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` for tagging. Simply because it is not guaranteed that all pipelines will run in the same order, and this alone can create issues. The same one you are currently experiencing.

I recommend to use `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` as it is bound to the pipeline. I would also rely on previous builds for caching and i will shortly outline my approach here

```yaml
stages:
  - create_builder_image
  - test
  - deploy

Create Builder Image:
  stage: create_builder_image
  script:
    - (docker pull $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG && export DOCKER_CACHE_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG) || (docker pull $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:latest && export DOCKER_CACHE_TAG=latest) || true
    - docker build --cache-from $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$DOCKER_CACHE_TAG ...
    # do stuff to build the image, using cache to speed it up
    - docker push $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$CI_COMMIT_SHA

Run Tests:
  image: $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  stage: test
  script:
    # do stuff in the context of the image build in the first stage

Push image: # pushing the image for the current branch ref, as i know it is a working image and it can than be used for caching by others.
  image: docker:20
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: push
  script:
    - docker pull $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker tag $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$CI_COMMIT_SHA $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    - docker push $GITLAB_IMAGE/builder:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
```

i know it might generate additional build steps, but this way, you can ensure that you will always have the image which belong to the pipeline. You still can use caching and layering from docker, and beneficiary, the image will not be pushed currently if the tests are failing.

Furthermore you can also create an step before creating the build image, where you can figure out, if you do need a new image at all.

Comment: Order of pipelines on the same branch _is_ guaranteed if you use the default project settings to 'auto cancel redundant pipelines'. So, I'm not sure that's the problem OP is having, unless that setting is disabled.